# color doesn't change correctly when clicked javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this drop-down list that has two options, blue and green. If I choose blue, whenever I click on the text input field, its background gets toggled between blue and black, which is text field background color. The same goes for red option. However, the code that I have only worked for the first and second time. From the third time, even if I choose red it toggles between blue and another color. 
This is my HTML:

Does anyone know what wrong? I'm thinking maybe I don't fully understand how jquery's change function works.

```js
$('#change_color').on('change', function() {
  //get the text value of the option chosen

  var colorOption = $("#change_color option:selected").text();

  //if option chosen is red then allow change input box to red
  if (colorOption === 'Red') {
    $('.my-input').click(function(inputBox) {
      $(inputBox.target).toggleClass('red');
    });
  }

  //if option is chosen is red then allow change input box to blue
  else {
    $('.my-input').click(function(inputBox) {
      $(inputBox.target).toggleClass('blue');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.my-input {
  background-color: black;
  width: 5%;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 5%;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 5%;
  font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="change_color" class="form-control box-border" placeholder="SPECIAL CHAR">
  <option selected disabled>Special Char</option>
  <option>Red</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="my-input">
<input type="text" class="my-input">
<input type="text" class="my-input">
```

Comment: It's important to understand what methods like `.click` or `.on` actually *do*. In your case, these are not triggering an event to occur; they are adding a *listener*. By repeatedly calling `.click` on the same element, you are stacking events over and over again.

Comment: exactly, I put console.log($(inputBox.target)) to see what they doing and saw a bunch of them stacking up. Do you have a fix?

Comment: I've submitted an answer.

Comment: alright thanks I will check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `$(element).click(...)`, you are attaching a new listener to that element. If you do this repeatedly, those listeners will stack. In your example, each time you change the dropdown, you're adding a new event - **not** replacing the previous one.

Instead, the easiest approach might be something like this:

- Have a global variable that stores the color
- Attach a change event to your dropdown. When changed, set the global color variable to the selected option
- Attach a click event to your inputs. When clicked, set the background to the global color variable

That would look like so:

```js
let backgroundColor;                                //Global var to hold color choice

$("#change_color").on("change", function() {        //When <select> changes
  backgroundColor = $(this).val();                  //Update global var
}).change();                                        //Fire this event on page-load

$(".my-input").on("click", function() {             //When input is clicked
  $(this).toggleClass(backgroundColor);             //Toggle class
});
```

```css
.my-input { background-color: black; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="change_color">
  <option>blue</option>
  <option>red</option>
</select>

<input class="my-input" />
<input class="my-input" />
<input class="my-input" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfgjboy2/2/)

Find the jsfiddle above.

You can use just `$('.my-input')` to call a click event, remove all classes and then do the check to see what `colorOption` you chose.

```js
//if option chosen is red then allow change input box to red
$('.my-input').click(function(inputBox) {
  colorOption = $("#change_color option:selected").text();
  $(this).removeClass();
  colorOption === 'Red' ? $(inputBox.target).addClass('red') : $(inputBox.target).addClass('blue');
});
```

```css
.my-input {
  background-color: black;
  width: 5%;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 5%;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 5%;
  font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="change_color" class="form-control box-border" placeholder="SPECIAL CHAR">
  <option selected disabled>Special Char</option>
  <option>Red</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="my-input">
<input type="text" class="my-input">
<input type="text" class="my-input">
```